# foreach if user clicked on link?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im using lightgallery so i need to load images before call them in lightgallery. Problem is that images are large so it takes too much time to load. Is there any way to load that specific gallery when user click on link.

```
<div id="lightgallery-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="hidelightgallery">
    <?php
    foreach ($files as $image) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
        $attachment_title = get_the_title($image->ID);
        $caption = get_post_field('post_excerpt', $image->ID);
        ?>

      <a class="item" href="<?php echo $image_attributes ?>"  data-sub-html="<?php echo $attachment_title; ?> <?php if($caption!= '') echo ' - ' ?> <?php echo $caption ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_attributes ?>"></a>
     <?php } ?>
     </div>
```

Now what i want is if user click for example link with this id then do foreach. Is that possible?

Comment: you can use ajax in this case, why thinking complicated, on click of link, just fire ajax, get the data and populate

Comment: Or other way around to do this, hide foreach populated html until you click

Comment: i dont want to hide like i said large images so it took a lot of time to page get load

Comment: Then use ajax..

Comment: do u have any idea how can i do that ? i know how ajax works but from my code to get data and populate its al iittle bit complicated?

Comment: see https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins article to use ajax in wp.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps,

1. create new template / html page where you will write html and populate by foreach loop
2. add your id = lightgallery whole code to that html page
3. when you will click on your link (which you mentioned) fire an ajax
4. Ajax function will get some id or number of images need to show or your logic on how you will populate data in foreach loop
5. in php you will get all relevant data, and you will populate that data in html file you created in step 1
6. php function will return that data to ajax function
7. Ajax function will get all your dynamic html data
8. populate that html where ever you want or just append that html wherever you want

Go step by step, this will solve your problem.

Comment: im using wordpress, is that a problem because there is no html page everything is .php?

Comment: so create php, write your html code in that, and get that dynamically generated data and return to js ajax response